# how to add a css class in javascript to be used onload

Tags: javascript

I am trying to load a popup lightbox window when the page is initially opened. I can get it to work on a click but I cannot get the code right to add a class in the script. I am using 'Lightbox' from within HTML Kickstart.

The link that works looks like this: `<a class="lightbox" href="#bbc">BBC</a>` This works perfectly. Basically how do I get that to work automatically on page load.

My attempt at the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load() {
        var target = location.href = "#bbc";
        target.className = "lightbox";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `<body onload="load()">` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/it/learn/javascript

Comment: @AkshayJoy w3fools.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call function on page load in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593145/how-to-call-function-on-page-load-in-js)

Answer (score 1):

So I assume you want to add a class to that anchor tag:

```
$(function () {
    $("a[href=#bbc]").addClass("lightbox");
});
```

Using `$(function() {…})` is the same as using the [`ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function (in JQuery). I would recommend running the code after the DOM is ready rather the "on load".

Answer (score 0):

you need to call the `load()` function on the `onLoad` event of `<body>` tag.

```
<body onLoad="load()">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var target = location.href = "#bbc";
    target.className = "lightbox";
});
```

Comment: I think OP wants using `JavaScript` not `jQuery`.

Comment: @user2428069 : But I think using `jQuery` will much easier than core `JavaScript`

Comment: @PradipKharbuja HTML Kickstart is a jQuery library so it's fair to assume the OP can use a jQuery solution. And please don't use code formatting for something that isn't code.

Comment: Sorry if he must not use jQuery, i always forgot to check if it needed. But my solution should work.

Comment: Why do you define the function `load` inside the event handler and call it immediately? Just put the two lines of code directly in the event handler. No need to define a second function.

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this question — ignoring the title — is that the user is trying to trigger the lightbox on load. Whilst this may be a wrong assumption, the way to trigger a link using javascript is to use the `.click()` method:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var i, list = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for ( i=0; i<list.length; i++ ) {
    /// this will only work for links with only a class name of lightbox.
    /// you could look into using getElementsByClassName or something similar.
    /// I use getElementsByTagName because I know how supported it is.
    if ( list[i].className == 'lightbox' ) {
      list[i].click();
    }
  }
};
```

The above code would support multiple lightbox links in a page, which might not be desired, so it may be best just to add an `id` to the link you wish to target and then use:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('clickonload').click();
};

<a id="clickonload" class="lightbox" href="#bbc">BBC</a>
```

You may find however, that in reading the documentation for whatever lightbox plugin you are using, that there is a command you can use from JavaScript, rather than clicking a target link.